# TS - how to restore the old --noImplicitAny behaviour

Tags: typescript, configuration

could someone tell me how to archieve the situation, where code like

```
let x;
```

will throw an exception and won't emit it? I really prefer the behaviour from TS versions before 2.1. Maybe TSlint could resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that since 2.1 when you assign to `x` it will infer the actual type rather than just using `any`. Before you assign the number to `x` it may appear it has type `any` but in fact trying to use it you'll find it starts with the type `undefined`.

It doesn't show in your one-line example but until you assign to `x` you can only use it as `undefined` and after assigning to it the type widens or changes accordingly.

Consider this code:

```
function foo(z: boolean) {
  let x;
  if (x) {   // Editor sees the type here as `undefined`
    x.foo(); // Error here, the type of `x` is now `never`
  }

  x = 3;     // `x` now has type `number`
  if (z) {
    x = 'foo'; // `x` now has type `string`
  }
  let y = x;   // Both `x` and `y` now have type `string|number`
  console.log(y.toFixed()); // Error, `toFixed` does not exist on `string|number`
}
```

Change the definition to `let x:any;` and this code will compile without complaint, because here the type of `x` really is `any`.

```
function foo(z: boolean) {
  let x: any;

  x = 3;
  if (z) {
    x = 'foo';
  }
  let y = x;
  console.log(y.toFixed()); 
}
```

The type of `y` is explicitly `any` because it is inferred from the type of `x`.

So going back to your one liner:

```
let x;
```

this is not an implicit `any` because the inferred type is `undefined`.

And to answer the question, no you can't turn off the type inferencing.

Comment: Thanks. Especially your last sentence help me a lot :). But I must to be a little bit stubborn. Is there no way to turn of the type inferencing by using TSLint or sth like that? Thanks in advance :)